# Why do I get different pointer values after an assignment?

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

so I am currently learning C++ and trying to get a hang of the relationship between arrays and pointers. The code below shows the assignments I have made.

```
int A[4] = {20, 30, 40, 50};
int p = A[0];
int* q = &p;
```

Now, if I print out the pointer values, I get this:

```
A == 0x7ffda1cb1ea0
&A == 0x7ffda1cb1ea0
&A[0] == 0x7ffda1cb1ea0
&p == 0x7ffda1cb1e94
q == 0x7ffda1cb1e94
&q == 0x7ffda1cb1e98
```

I don't really understand why the values for &A[0] and &p are different, even though the assignment ist p = A[0]. I also don't understand how there are only 4 bytes between q and &q, even though the size of q is shown as 8. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `p` stores the value of first element of the array. It has another address.

Comment: A pointer is a *variable*. The *address* of a pointer is not the same as the *contents* of that pointer.

Comment: `int p = A[0];` copies `A[0]` into a new variable `p` which will of course have a different address than the array `A` it was copied from.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I don't really understand why the values for &A[0] and &p are different

They are different objects in memory, so they have different addresses. `A[4]` is one object, `p` is another one and `q` is another one. The assignment makes them hold the same value, but they're still two different objects. You can remove the assignment and the result will be the same.

> I also don't understand how there are only 4 bytes between q and &q,
>   even though the size of q is shown as 8

`q` is set to the address of `p`, and `&p` gives you the address of `q`. The result of `4` makes sense, because that's how big `p` is. That's why `q` comes `4` after `p`, because `p` takes up `4` bytes.

---

Perhaps it's more clear if you try the same thing with a reference:

```
int A[4] = { 20, 30, 40, 50 };
int &p = A[0]; // note the "&", this makes p a reference
std::cout << "&A[0]: " << &A[0] << std::endl << "&p:    " << &p << std::endl;
```

For me, this results in:

```
&A[0]: 008FFD90
&p:    008FFD90
```

Now `p` isn't a separate object that can hold a copy of a data, but an actual reference to the same place.

Comment: It would be better to say "they are different *objects*". They may well be global variables; it wouldn't matter.

Comment: @PeterA.Schneider you're right, I think that's the better abstraction, too.

Comment: Oh, and you should print `&A[0]` if you expect its address, not `&A[4]` ;-) Then you'll get the same address as for `&p`, which I thought was the whole point ;-). If you then mention that a reference is just another name for the same object it will become clear why the addresses are the same.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I understand now.

Answer (score 3):

> I don't really understand why the values for &A[0] and &p are different

`A[0]` and `p` are separate objects. Each object has an unique address during their life time (except certain cases involving subobjects). The life time of `A[0]` and `p` overlap.  Therefore `&A[0]` and `&p` cannot possibly be the same.

> even though the assignment ist p = A[0]

Assignment has no effect on where an object is stored. It can only affect the value that is stored in the object.

> also don't understand how there are only 4 bytes between q and &q, even though the size of q is shown as 8

The size of `q` is irrelevant, since it points to a lower address. The size of `p` happens to be 4:

```
 /-offset from p
/  object in memory
00 p (first byte) \
01 p               |
02 p               |
03 p               |
04 q (first byte)  | Distance between p and q: 4
05 q 
06 q
07 q
08 q
09 q
10 q
11 q
```

Answer (score 1):

When you are doing int p = A[0] you are simply assigning the value of A[0] to p. They are both different objects and are stored at different locations.
The value of &p will not change if you change the value of p.

The gap of 4 is due to the size of p it is not related to the size of q